# How to correctly use Expression Trees on properties (without reflection)

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

**Objective**: process an object and if the object implements an expected type, I want to change a specific property value (this part is working fine), and I also would like to apply the same logic to all property lists (that I explicit point) that are of the same expected type.

I have the following code:

```
public abstract class BaseObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Father : BaseObject
{
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ChildA> Children1 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ChildB> Children2 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ChildA> Children3 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ChildB> Children4 { get; set; }
}

public class ChildA : BaseObject
{
    public int Val1 { get; set; }
}

public class ChildB : BaseObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

I want to process an object by applying some changes on a specific property on the target object and on all property children that I explicit say:

```
public void Start()
{
    var listA = new List<ChildA> { new ChildA { Id = 1, Val1 = 1 }, new ChildA { Id = 2, Val1 = 2 } };
    var listB = new List<ChildB> { new ChildB { Id = 1, Name = "1", Total = 1 } };
    var obj = new Father { Id = 1, CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, Name = "F1", ChildrenA = listA, ChildrenB = listB };

    // I explicit tell to process only 2 of the 4 lists....
    ProcessObj(obj, x => new object[] { x.Children1, x.Children2 });            
}
```

I was able to write this function:

```
public void ProcessObj<T>(T obj, Expression<Func<T, object[]>> includes = null)
{
    var objBaseObject = obj as BaseObject;
    if (objBaseObject == null) return;

    // Here I change the ID - add 100 just as an example....
    objBaseObject.Id = objBaseObject.Id + 100;

    if (includes == null) return;

    var array = includes.Body as NewArrayExpression;
    if (array == null) return;

    var exps = ((IEnumerable<object>)array.Expressions).ToArray();
    for (var i = 0; i < exps.Count(); i++)
    {
        var name = ((MemberExpression)exps[i]).Member.Name;
        var childProperty = obj.GetType().GetProperties(
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance
               ).FirstOrDefault(prop => prop.Name == name);
        if (childProperty == null) continue;

        // NOT correct because I think I am getting a copy of the object 
        // and not pointing to the object in memory (by reference)
        var childList = childProperty.GetValue(obj); 

        // TODO: loop on the list and apply the same logic as the father.... 
        // change the ID field....
    }
}
```

In this prototype I started writing reflection, but I really would like to avoid it if possible....

How can I do this???

Comment: This is an aside, but for the usefulness of the method, since it only does anything for a T of BaseObject, why not add `where T : BaseObject` to your method?

Comment: Sure, that could be added as well, thanks for pointing that.

Comment: Why is the whole rigmarole with reflection (and expression trees are a kind of reflection too, make no mistake) even needed? The only line in the whole mess of code above that performs useful work is `objBaseObject.Id = objBaseObject.Id + 100`. Any reason you can't pass a delegate containing that to a `foreach` that simply twiddles things at compile time? Maybe write a visitor if you must work recursively?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I wrote the Expression list in order to not pass a string array. Regarding the "no use" of delegate, since I want to apply this to a more complicated case, I thought that it would be nice to not need to pass a delegate as parameter (and also because later I want to make this recursive)...  and also I would not like to write a delegate per target list. Perhaps its possible to do this more easily, but I lack knowledge on this matter.... :(

Comment: I believe you've got a case of Really Dumb Objects that consequently need to be propped up by really clever code. You may want to consider making your objects less dumb and giving them methods to do stuff that can work with the benefit of knowing their context (`Father.ApplyOneTwo(b => b.ID += 100)`). However, that goes into code review territory, which is not really within the scope of SO. One question that remains relevant: is *everything* you want to do with the objects determined at compile time? If so, reflection can be avoided, otherwise not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems like you're complicating the problem by using expression trees. Can you just not use a regular Action and Func delegates to do this? Why do they need to be expression trees? Here's an example just using delegates:

```
public void ProcessObj<T>(T obj, Func<T, IEnumerable<object>> includes) {
     var objBaseObject = obj as BaseObject;
    if (objBaseObject == null) return;


    // Create a reusable action to use on both the parent and the children
    Action<BaseObject> action = x => x.Id += 100;

    // Run the action against the root object
    action(objBaseObject);

    // Get the includes by just invoking the delegate. No need for trees.
    var includes = includes(obj);

    // Loop over each item in each collection. If the types then invoke the same action that we used on the root. 
    foreach(IEnumerable<object> include in includes) 
    {
       foreach(object item in include) 
       {
          var childBaseObject = item as BaseObject;
          if(childBaseObject != null) 
          {
            action(childBaseObject);          
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Useable just like before:

ProcessObj(obj, x => new object[] { x.Children1, x.Children2 });

No expression trees and no reflection, just regular delegate lambdas.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks once again ;)